# Cumulative sum in R by group and start over when sum of values in group larger than maximum value

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

The function below groups values in a vector based on whether the cumulative sum has reached a certain max value and then starts over.

```
cs_group <- function(x, threshold) {
  cumsum <- 0
  group <- 1
  result <- numeric()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    cumsum <- cumsum + x[i]
    if (cumsum > threshold) {
      group <- group + 1
      cumsum <- x[i]
    }
    result = c(result, group)
  }
  return (result)
}
```

## Example

The max value in the example is 10. The first group only included 9; because summing it with the next value would result in a sum of 12. The next group includes 3, 2, 2 (+8 would result in a value higher then 10).

```
test <- c(9, 3, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 9, 1)
cs_group(test, 10)
[1] 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 5 5
```

However, I prefer to include in each group the value that results in the cumulative sum to be higher than the maximum value of 10.

Ideal result:

[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4

Comment: `However, I prefer to include in each group the value that results in the cumulative sum to be higher than the maximum value of 10.` I don't understand this. Can you explain the ideal result some more.

Comment: shouldn't the last value be 4?

Comment: No, because of the restriction that the last group should be >= max. value and <max.value*2.

Comment: and what if the last value is 5 in this case i.e `> max.value*2` ? What would be expected output in this case?

Comment: You're right about that. That wouldn't work. So the value in test represents group 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `purrr` approach could be:

```
cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(accumulate(test, ~ ifelse(.x >= 10, .y, .x + .y))) <= 0))

[1] 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
```

Comment: This does not seem to work if the first value in test is 10 or more. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please specify what is the expected result for `test <- c(10, 9, 3, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 9, 1)`? To me, it seems to work.

Comment: So that would be 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5. Thanks

Comment: I got the same results, just starting with zero. Don't you too? Also, `identical(cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(accumulate(test, ~ ifelse(.x >= 10, .y, .x + .y))) < 0)) + 1,
          c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5))` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: I had to be more specific. What if the first two values are 10 or larger? Both then are place in the same group, which is not correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own custom function or use the code written by others.

[I had the exact same problem](https://github.com/ekstroem/MESS/issues/4) few days back and this has been included in the `MESS` package.

```
devtools::install_github("ekstroem/MESS")
MESS::cumsumbinning(test, 10, cutwhenpassed = TRUE)
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

Comment: It's a really neat function! I'm just curious that based on what does it determine that the last value belong to the same group?

Comment: @tmfmnk I don't have my system right now to check this but I think the last value should be 4.

Comment: Maybe my interpretation is wrong, but I would think that the groups go as following: 1 = 9, 3 (sum = 12), 2 = 2, 2, 8 (sum = 12), 3 = 5, 4, 9 (sum = 18) and 4 = 1 (sum = 1).

Comment: Exactly and this is what `cumsumbinning` does when `cutwhenpassed = TRUE`.

Comment: Sorry, I had the impression that the last value in your output was in the same group as the others before it :) +1.

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose, your `cs_group` can be written like below (if I understand the logic behind in a correct way):

```
cs_group <- function(x, threshold) {
  group <- 1
  r <- c()
  repeat {
    if (length(x)==0) break
    cnt <- (idx <- max(which(cumsum(x) <= threshold)))+ifelse(idx==length(x),0,1)
    r <- c(r,rep(group, cnt))
    x <- x[-(1:cnt)]
    group <- group + 1
  }
  r
}
```

such that

```
test <- c(9, 3, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 9, 1)
> cs_group(test, 10)
[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
```